# How to remove Hyper-V DNS records

Tags: windows-10, dns, hyper-v, ipconfig

My dns entries show 2 different IPs for a Hyper-V Virtual Machine (even when the VM is off):

```
ipconfig /displaydns

winhost.mshome.net
----------------------------------------
No records of type AAAA


winhost.mshome.net
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : winhost.mshome.net
A (Host) Record . . . : 172.23.125.25


Record Name . . . . . : winhost.mshome.net
A (Host) Record . . . : 172.29.33.168
```

Notes:

- These entries do not exist in the hosts file (`c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- I've tried these reset functions (as Admin - did not work):

  1. `ipconfig /flushdns`
  2. `ipconfig /registerdns`
  3. `ipconfig /release`
  4. `ipconfig /renew`
  5. `netsh winsock reset`
  6. Restart the computer.

How can I delete these entries?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 places that I know of that ipconfig /displaydns will reference and they are both in the same directory:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\

ipconfig /displaydns will reference both the hosts. and the hosts.ics file

When creating new virtual machines in Hyper-V, it automatically places entries in hosts.ics .  This was driving me insane as well - I was going nuts over my arp tables and dns cache with ipconfig.  You can just remove the entries in the hosts.ics and you won't even have to flush the DNS.

Comment: There is a very old bug in the Default Switch modifying the hosts.ics file. When it updates it and the new content is shorter than the old, it does not truncate the file. Thus the file often has garbage at the end that is causing problems. I've tried to report it using the feedback hub application, but it just gets ignored.